# Express.js Send Files with Hashed File Names Compiled in Webpack

Tags: express, webpack

This seemed pretty straightforward but I've searched a while and haven't found any solutions. If there's a better way to set this up, I'm open to suggestions.

When I change code in `index.html` in the below folder structure and compile with Webpack (which outputs with a new hash in filename), how do I write my Express.js route so that I don't have to change the filename everytime I compile with Webpack? Here's my setup:

**Folder Structure:**

```
root/
-dist/
--- index.1de575730aa45442d6bc.html
-src/
--- index.html
--- index.js
-webpack.static.config.js
-server/
--- server.js
```

**Express Route:**

```
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(/*dynamically send index.[hash].html here*/);
});
```

**webpack.static.config.js**

```
if(process.cwd() !== __dirname) process.chdir(__dirname);

const path = require('path');
const webpack = require('webpack');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const dotenv = require('dotenv');

const env = dotenv.config().parsed;
const definition = Object.keys(env).reduce((variables, key, i) => {
    variables[key] = JSON.stringify(env[key]);
    return def;
}, {});

const minify = {
    collapseWhitespace: true,
    keepClosingSlash: true,
    removeComments: true,
    removeRedundantAttributes: true,
    removeScriptTypeAttributes: true,
    removeStyleLinkTypeAttributes: true,
    useShortDoctype: true
};

module.exports = {
    module: {
        rules: [
            { test: /\.html$/i, use: 'html-loader' },
            { test: /\.js$/i, use: 'babel-loader' },
            { test: /\.css$/i, use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader'] },
            { test: /\.(csv|tsv)$/i, use: ['csv-loader'] },
            { test: /\.xml$/i, use: ['xml-loader'] },
            { test: /\.(png|jpg|jpeg|svg|gif)$/i, type: 'asset/resource', generator: {filename: 'img/[name].[hash][ext][query]'} },
            { test: /\.(woff|woff2|eot|ttf|otf)$/i, type: 'asset/resource', generator: {filename: 'fonts/[name].[hash][ext][query]'} }
        ]
    },
    entry: {
        home: './src/index.js'
    },
    output: {
        filename: '[name].[hash].bundle.js',
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist')
    },
    plugins: [
        new webpack.optimize.ModuleConcatenationPlugin(),
        new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
        new webpack.DefinePlugin(definition),
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({ minify, template: path.resolve('./src/index.html'), filename: 'index.[hash].html', chunks: ['home'] })
    ]
};
```

Comment: Show your webpack config

Comment: @slideshowp2, just added it. let me know if there's anything else I can add that would help

Answer (score 0):

Don't know is it still relevant, but I had the same problem recently.
Solved it with `readdir` method built in Node.js File System Module:

Require file system module and path module:

```
const path = require('path')
const fs = require('fs')
```

Change path to folder, where your "html" file is placed:

```
const pathName = path.resolve(__dirname, '../client/dist')

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    fs.readdir(pathName, (err, files) => {
        if (err) {
            console.error(err)
            return res.status(500)
        }
        const filename = files.find(file => path.extname(file) === '.html')
        res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, '../client/dist', filename))
    })
})
```

`fs.readdir` method returns array of all files in given directory, so you have to get one with ".html" extension. `path.extname` is method from Path Module that returns the extension of a file path.
It worked for me, but maybe there is more elegant solution.

P.S.: Or you could just remove "[hash]" from "filename" option in `HtmlWebpackPlugin` in webpack.static.config.js file.